# i want to loop or similar method the following code in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

This is my code.

```
declare @dt datetime;
declare @AddTime int;
declare @earliestTime int;
declare @latestTime int;
declare @basedTime int;

set @dt = cast('01-01-1980 00:00:00' as datetime)
select @earliestTime = min(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dt, starttime)) from visit
select @latestTime = max(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dt, starttime)) from visit
set @AddTime = 30;
set @basedTime = @earliestTime;
set @earliestTime = @earliestTime + @AddTime;

SELECT
    count(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dt, starttime)) as 'Ticket Issued',
    @earliestTime as 'Period',
    count(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dt, nexttime)) as 'Called Tickets',
    SUM(case when DATEDIFF(second, starttime, nexttime) <= 900 then 1 else 0 end)
        as 'Less than Accepted Waiting Time'
    from visit
    where DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dt, starttime)between @basedTime and @earliestTime
```

What I want is.. I want to do the query again and again till @earliestTime > @latestTime

I know I am supposed to use stored procedure.. But I am not sure how to use that..

Comment: @william: I think you have been a member of SO long enough to know how to format code....

Comment: What is SO? you mean this would b an easy method?

Comment: @william: I'm saying how about you format your own code!

Comment: @william: also, rather than saying "This is my code:" - say what your goal is, rather than a perceived solution to a problem. This tends to get better results.

Comment: @william: So, you're not going to format your code? Select the text, click the 'curly bracket' button. It's not difficult...

Comment: tkz.. i actually dun know.. how to do that..

Comment: FYI: be very careful with the use of `BETWEEN` when working with `datetime` columns where you have a time component involved. You may see unexpected/erroneous results near the upper endpoint without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
create table #temp TicketIssued numeric(9), Period datetime,
CalledTickets numeric(9), LessThanAcceptedWaitingTime numeric(9);

while(@earliestTime > @latestTime)
begin
set @earliestTime=@earliestTime+@AddTime;
insert into #temp
(SELECT 
count(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dt, starttime)) as 'Ticket Issued',
@earliestTime as 'Period',
count(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dt, nexttime)) as 'Called Tickets',
SUM(case when DATEDIFF(second, starttime, nexttime) <=900 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Less than Accepted Waiting Time'
from visit
where DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dt, starttime)between @basedTime and @earliestTime)
end

select * from #temp
```

hope this helps

Comment: But this results lots of tables. How to get it in one table?

Comment: create a temporary table before while loop and perform insert inside the while loop

Comment: if its a procedure, you dont need to drop